# How can I enable IdeaVim on only the main editor window?

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

IdeaVim current replaces essentially all multi-line text inputs. For example, Git commit messages and the Clojure REPL both accept Vim commands. However, in those situations, I'd prefer to have a simple text input, without Vim's features.

Is there any way to enable IdeaVim only on the main editor window, and disable it on all other text inputs? If not, is there any way to disable it or configure it differently for different text inputs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of November 2020 (and IdeaVIM 0.61), this is fully possible by setting the following in your .ideavimrc file:

`set dialogescape=off` (disables IdeaVIM in all dialogs | defaults to legacy - the old behaviour)

`set oneline=off` (disables IdeaVIM only in single line boxes | defaults to on)

Comment: Hi! These 2 options were removed after the EAP. Now there is a single option `ideavimsupport` https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/doc/set-commands.md

Answer (score 4):

The following line will disable IdeaVim from dialogs

```
set ideavimsupport=
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible. Feel free to vote for [VIM-765](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-765) and [VIM-740](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-740).